# Consuming Java String Array to set Key Value Pairs

Tags: java, arrays

Having trouble keeping state in mind here. Appreciate any help. I have a string that is set by end users and has no validation and is open text. I need to take this in and set key value pairs. I ignore all other lines (e.g: starting with : or !) I do know that the key will start with a dash (e.g: -filePickupDir) and then the value will either be after the next space or after the next space with newline character. If there is a continuation slash (), then I know there is another key value pair. Some examples on how the users may have put this in place:

> -filePickupDir /export/home/PickupDir/ \

or

> -filePickupDir \
>
> /export/home/AdjPickupDir/ \

Example Code:

```
HashMap<String, String> processMap = new HashMap<>();
    String jobProcess = job.getProcess(); //this is a method that gets the string
    String lines[] = jobProcess.split("[\\r\\n]+");

    int varCount = 0;
    for (String s: lines) {
        String key = "";
        String val = "";
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        if (s.startsWith("!")) {

        } else if (s.startsWith(":")) {

        } else if (s.startsWith("-")) {
            count = s.length() - s.replace(" ", "").length();
            count2 = s.length() - s.replace("\\", "").length();
            System.out.println("Line space count: " + count + " continue line count: " + count2);
            if (count == 1 && count2 == 0 || count == 3 && count2 == 1 || count == 1 && count2 == 1) {
                s = s.trim();
                int keyIndex = s.indexOf("-");
                keyIndex = +1;
                int firstSpaceIndex = s.indexOf(" ");
                int spaceAfterFirstSpaceIndex = firstSpaceIndex + 1;
                int lastIndex = s.length();
                String keyString = s.substring(keyIndex, firstSpaceIndex);
                String valueString = s.substring(spaceAfterFirstSpaceIndex, lastIndex);
                if (count == 3 && count2 == 1) {
                    int removeSlashIndex = valueString.length();
                    valueString = valueString.substring(1, removeSlashIndex - 3);
                }
            } else if (count == 1 && count2 == 1) {
                //value is on the next line
                //We need to let the program know we have a key but no value and need to maintain state
            }

            //String split = String.valueOf(s.split("^-(\\w|\\d|\\s)+"));
            //System.out.println("split is: "+split.toString());


        } else {
            //This is value if the key is on its own line above
            s = s.trim();
            System.out.println("Value: " + s);
        }
    }
```

I'm having problems wrapping my head around keeping state here. I basically just need a key that starts with a slash (-) and then the value is the next string separated by either a space or a space and a newline. Continue processing until all key pairs are found.

Example String array to consume:

> -hostIds \
>
> 9 \
>
> -maxRecords \
>
> 1000 \
>
> -xsl \
>
> $batchslx/ziproot/EmailXsl

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use Regex to do this.
You can capture the first example like this:

```
String firstTest = "-filePickupDir /export/home/PickupDir/ \\";

//the capture groups are in the parantheses
String patternString = "[\\n\\s]?-(\\w+)(.+)\\\\";

Pattern pat =  Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher match = pat.matcher(firstTest);
match.find();

System.out.println(match.group(0)); //whole String
System.out.println(match.group(1)); //first capture group
System.out.println(match.group(2)); //second capture group
//results:
//0 -filePickupDir /export/home/PickupDir/ \
//1 filePickupDir
//2 /export/home/PickupDir/
```

If you further extend the regex you will be able to capture exactly as you described.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I ended up leaving it as a String and dropped the String array. Then removed the newline and backslash continuation characters:

`String patternString = "[\\n\\s]?-(\\w+)(\\s+)([^\\s]+)";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher match = pat.matcher(lines);
match.matches();

int lastMatchPos = 0;
while (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group(1)); 
    System.out.println(match.group(3)); 
    lastMatchPos = match.end();
}`